# Access fields tables relations with LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq, relation

I have two tables: Post and User.

the User has an Id and Name... fields.
and the Post has an userId and Title... fields.

im using linq, and i want to be able to write something like this:

```
var post = dc.Posts.FirstOrDefault();
var user = post.User;
```

then i want to be able to do: `post.User.Name` ...

help please..

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using Entity Framework. Make sure that you have navigation properties on your entities, and that lazy loading is enabled. Your code should work then:

```
var post = dc.Posts.FirstOrDefault();
if (post != null)
    name = post.User.Name;
```

Also you can do eager loading of User entity when you are loading post:

```
var post = dc.Posts.Include(p => p.User).FirstOrDefault();
if (post != null)
    name = post.User.Name;
```

Comment: thanks for the replay.
the fast is that im new to this can u explain with more details please.. im using dbml file